# How to write a file to xml with STAX?

Tags: java, xml, io, stax

I have a problem writing a file to a xml.
Here is how this element looks in xsd.

```
<xs:element name="File">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">   
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Here is my method to write:

```
       private void writeFile (XMLStreamWriter2 sw, final InputStream is){
//is - inputstream from file
            try {
                OutputStream output = null;
                InputStream input = new Base64InputStream(is, true);
                int count;

                    int BUFFER_SIZE = 4000;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    output = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\test.txt"));
                    while ((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                            output.write(buffer, 0, count);
                            sw.writeBinary(buffer, 0, count);

                    }
                    is.close();
                    input.close();
                    output.close();
            } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(StaxFinal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(StaxFinal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
        }
```

The content of test.txt is valid base-64 string, while content of `File` xml elements file is not (i'm checking with http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/). why

**EDIT**
Trying to use this, but i get a lot of carriage-return symbols `#xd;`

```
private void writeFile (XMLStreamWriter sw, InputStream is){
   //is - FileInputStream
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new Base64InputStream(is, true));
    char[] buf = new char[4096];
    int n;

        while( (n = reader.read(buf)) >= 0 ) {
                sw.writeCharacters(buf, 0, n-3 );
        }
}
```

**EDIT**
Method:

```
writeRaw(char[] chars, int i, int i1)
```

works fine. Strange, but woodstox's `readElementAsBinary` reads and decodes base64 for me. Why `writeBinary` doesn't write valid base64? 
Anyways, thank you skaffman! You are awesome!

Comment: `writeBinary` is a proprietary method in the Woodstox STAX implementation, and as such you shouldn't really be using it.  Stick to the standard `XMLStreamWriter` interface.

Comment: Wow thanks. But how to write from stream? Using `writeCharacters(char[] text, int start, int len)`???

Comment: Yes. XML can only represent character data, so if you choose to write base64-encoded binary data as character data, then you should be encoding it yourself. The Woodstox `writeBinary` stuff is for their high-performance webservice support (e.g. Fast Infoset), so you should avoid it unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Please look at my edit. How to get rid of #xd; symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the Base64InputStream from Apache Commons Codec. It also offers a constructor with four arguments, that can be used to turn off line breaks completely.
Adjusting your method from the question you can write valid Base64 output like this:

```
private void writeFile (XMLStreamWriter sw, InputStream is){
    //is - FileInputStream
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new Base64InputStream(is, true, -1, null));
    char[] buf = new char[4096];
    int n;
    while( (n = reader.read(buf)) >= 0 ) {
        sw.writeCharacters(buf, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the javadoc of Base64InputStream: if you provide two parameters to the constructor (InputStream in, boolean doEncode) then it *creates a Base64InputStream such that all data read is either Base64-encoded or Base64-decoded from the original provided InputStream.* and *doEncode - true if we should encode all data read from us, false if we should decode.*

Because I am not sure of what your function should do, I can only recon this:

- either you could turn doEncode to false (to store a decoded text in your xml file)
- or simply use the inputstream *is* directly (to copy/paste the text file towards the xml)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need to store encoded text in xml (xsd requirment). I don't understand why test.txt is ok, while xml content is not.

Comment: Change InputStream input = new Base64InputStream(is, true); to InputStream input = is;

Comment: changed, opened created xml, copied text from File element, pasted to that online decoder i linked, `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. `